# How to get child object from parent with one to many relation in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I have a parent object what an account is. This account object has a one to many relation with its child object what a mailList is.

```
Parent:

    class CusAccount
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->mailList = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MailList", mappedBy="account")
         */
        private $mailList;

        /**
        * Get mailList
        *
        * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
        */
        public function getMailList()
        {
              return $this->mailList;
        }

    }

Child:

class MailList
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CusAccount")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $account;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=50)
    *
    */
   private $email;

}
```

Adding multiple childs to the parent works fine. I double check in the databse. Also getting the first child back works with:

```
$child = $account->getMailinglist()->first();
```

Only now I want to find a child by its email adres. I cannot find the correct code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the collection to find what you need:

```
$allChildrenWithSearchedEmail = $account->getMailinglist()->filter(function($child) {
    return ($child->getEmail() == "info@example.com");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to get the complete child list only ordered on email?

Comment: In that case you can get all entries as an array with `getMailinglist()->getValues()` and use `usort()` on that array.